# Out of memory error on emulator, not even using images in fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-memory

I am having an application which has different fragments and in one fragment, I have huge data . It runs perfectly fine for the first time but when I come on that fragment for 2nd time then "out of memory error" crops up. It was working absolutely fine some days back but all of a sudden I am facing this issue.

```
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921): "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x44170e10 self=0x4102c0
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   | sysTid=11419 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=3874832
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   | schedstat=( 15525608372 2207589326 340 )
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:~97)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:136)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:272)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:452)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at com.indiamart.helper.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:83)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at com.indiamart.loader.LoaderTaskBuyLead.doInBackground(LoaderTaskBuyLead.java:82)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at com.indiamart.loader.LoaderTaskBuyLead.doInBackground(LoaderTaskBuyLead.java:1)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
09-27 13:24:21.903: I/dalvikvm(10921):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-27 13:24:22.576: W/dalvikvm(10921): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:97)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:136)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:272)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:452)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at com.indiamart.helper.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:83)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at com.indiamart.loader.LoaderTaskBuyLead.doInBackground(LoaderTaskBuyLead.java:82)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at com.indiamart.loader.LoaderTaskBuyLead.doInBackground(LoaderTaskBuyLead.java:1)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-27 13:24:22.583: E/AndroidRuntime(10921):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: put doInBackground() code in try..catch() block

Comment: It is already in try-catch block

Comment: can you please help me with this

Comment: post your respective code need to review

Comment: JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
  JSONArray buyLead = null;
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try{
String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_BLBefLogin, "POST",    params);
   try {  
   buyLead = new JSONArray(json);
   if (buyLead != null) {
   for (int i = 0; i < buyLead.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject c = buyLead.getJSONObject(i);
ofr_desc=c.getString(TAG_OFR_DESC);
map.put(TAG_OFR_DESC, ofr_desc);
list.add(map);

Comment: parser classtry {
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line + "\n");
}
json = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
finally
{ 
try
{
reader.close();
is.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}

Comment: some 800 records are coming at a time

Comment: It is a limitation of json parser. You need to implement pagination at server side and get data from server in installment.